# Is there a function in OpenCV that does same function as Matlab Vision.blobAnalysis()?

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

Our target is Linux on an embedded system that cannot run Matlab.
We have computer vision Matlab script prototypes, and want this functionality (Vision.blobAnalysis) ported to embedded.

Two options:  Use Matlab CODER to port Matlab computer vision functionality to embedded, or reproduce functionality using openCV on embedded system.

Comment: You're probably looking for [connectedComponentsWithStats](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#connectedcomponents)

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple blob detector:

```
using namespace cv;
// Read image
Mat im = imread( "blob.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );

// Set up the detector with default parameters.
SimpleBlobDetector detector;

// Detect blobs.
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect( im, keypoints);

// Draw detected blobs as red circles.
// DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS flag ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
Mat im_with_keypoints;
drawKeypoints( im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0,0,255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS );

// Show blobs
imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints );
waitKey(0);
```